# Обнуление переменных в Python

Tags: python

В программе часто требуется обнулить несколько переменных. Как можно избежать многократного использования кусков вроде этого? Может, создать функцию с глобальными переменными для обнуления? Или класс?

```
a1 = 0
a2 = 0
...
an = 0
```

Comment: @FrozenTroll, надо не засорять глобальную область видимости и грамотно производить декомпозицию, в результате которой переменные и так разобьются по функциям/методам.  
Конкретный пример проще загнать в лист и обнулять: `a[i] = 0 for i in xrange(len(a))` или `a = [0]*len(a)`

Comment: А если мне нужно присвоить каждой из этих переменных какое-то конкретное "нулевое" значение?

Comment: инициализировать так:

    а = [0,1,1,2,0,4]

и это будет:

    a[0] = 0
    a[1] = 1
    ....
    a[5] = 4

Comment: Смотрите словарь globals (присутствует в `__builtins__`). А уж выбор или регулярками, или из заготовленного списка

    globals()['fuckedVar'] = 'Ooops'

Comment: Вопрос напомнил пример из раздела "Массивы" мануала по Spectrum Basic ([на английском](http://www.worldofspectrum.org/ZXBasicManual/zxmanchap12.html), на русском не нашел). Резюмирую: используйте списки.

Comment: Глобальные переменные это оочень плохо. Используйте локальные переменные.

Comment: похоже на [XY вопрос](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/795/23044). Вероятно следует избавиться от многократного изменения глобальных переменных или, по меньшей мере, следует коллекцию (список `a` к примеру) использовать вместо кучи a1,a2,...an переменных.

Answer (score 2):

## код

```
a=b=с=d=0
```

Глобальные переменные -- это зло, от них в python уйти легко и полезно.
Цикл решит ваши проблемы:

## код

```
def zero_fill(a=None):
    for i in xrange(0,len(a)):
        a[i]=0
```

Comment: Этот цикл решает только задачу обнуления переменных. А проблему он не решает, потому что проблема — в том, что глобальные переменные вообще используются.